# How to compare an empty value in a list

Tags: python

I have an array of string and I want to know how to add a string if some of the values is empty. P. eg:

```
array=["1","3","","7"]
```

With the previous array I want to save a string value in the third position of the array (2 index) because it is empty. How can I probe it?

Code:

```
if array[2]== ?:
```

What should I write instead of "?"

Comment: `if not array[2]` or `if array[2] == ''`

Comment: Did you consider an empty string `if array[2] == ""`?

Answer (score 0):

An empty string is equivalent to `False`, so you can simply do:

```
if not array[2]:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite nicely with a list comprehension in python:

```py
array=["1","3","","7"]

new_array = [x if x!="" else "replaced" for x in array]
new_array
```

returns

```
['1', '3', 'replaced', '7']
```